# Webcam not working with python interface to OpenCV 2.4 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, opencv, webcam

Yesterday I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on a brand new HD, ran all the updates (`sudo apt-get updates && sudo apt-get upgrade`), installed a bunch of stuff from apt (`sudo apt-get install git libsdl1.2-dev python-dev python-setuptools python-numpy python-scipy python-nose ipython python-pygame libcv-dev python-opencv`), then installed openCV 2.4 from source (following the instructions [here](http://shambool.com/2012/05/05/install-opencv-24-on-ubuntu-1204/)). However, when I attempt to use the python interface to capture an image from a webcam (I've tried both c910 and c920 models from logitech), I get "None" as the result:

```
>>> import cv
>>> webcam_stream = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0) #I've also tried cv.CaptureFromCAM(-1) with the same results
>>> this_image = cv.QueryFrame(webcam_stream)
>>> print(this_image)
None
```

Any ideas why this is failing? Webcam apps available from the Ubuntu software center (like Cheese) seem to grab images from the cameras just fine, so I'm very confused!

Comment: I'm considering to buy either C910 and C920. I wonder that could you make your cameras work with Ubuntu 12.04 and OpenCV? I'm asking because my setup is same with yours.

Answer (score 1):

Had exactly the same issue today, no idea why the webcam stopped working with openCV, to fix it I went into my OpenCV source build directory and ran sudo make install which worked - the answers with links to install howtos are pointless and misleading

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `v4l-utils` to set up the webcam. Here is a detailed step by step information about installing OpenCV 2.4 from source. http://jayrambhia.com/blog/install-opencv-2-4-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/